# (wx)Maxima: predicate test for nested lists in arrays

Tags: arrays, predicate, maxima, wxmaxima

I have an array of arrays of lists `allvals` and would like to check to see if any of the `allvals[i][j]` are empty.

<s>The following works, but isn't easy to read:</s> I thought the following worked, but I don't think it actually does...

```
some(lambda([anarrays], some( lambda([alist], some(lambda([e], e = true), alist) = true), anarrays ) = true), allvals)
```

Is there a better approach? I tried playing with `map` and `apply` but that was even worse, for me.

Any suggestions for a better workflow would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: the following *does* work:

```
map(lambda([anarray], apply('some, [emptyp, anarray])), allvals);
```

Comment: I know, I am old fashioned. But in this case, I would suggest to write 2 or 3 lines instead of one (map a list and then map an array of lists). This way you can test one, then the other and you need not guess as much where the problem might be.

Comment: Thank you -- I'm really not a programmer, so don't have any real preferences in terms of style: I just thought it was best to complete an operation in a single step, but I too find multiple lines clearer. Thanks for taking the time to share your suggestion. Having found a solution that works that is not very long or complicated, I think I need to focus on learning how to think about these tasks, more clearly...

Comment: It sounds like you are working with a list of lists of lists. Be careful to distinguish arrays and lists when you describe stuff in Maxima -- Maxima treats them differently.

Comment: Looks like you got something working, that's great. You can make it a little clearer by writing the test as `some(emptyp, anarray)` instead of the equivalent `apply('some, [emptyp, anarray])`. (Aside from saying, e.g., `alist` instead of `anarray`, as I was saying before.)